# how do i separate columns using sep= in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following table in a xlsx file:

```
emp_num | Name | Salary
551234 | Joe | 5000
551234 | Dan | 5001
551234 | James | 5002
551234 | Li | 5003
551234 | Suzi | 5004
```

Im trying to separate the columns by using `sep= " | "`
Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('I21.xlsx', sep=' | ', header=None)
```

After running the code this what i get:
I use `header=None` only to show more clearly that there only 1 column.

```
                         0
0  emp_num | Name | Salary
1      551234 | Joe | 5000
2      551234 | Dan | 5001
3    551234 | James | 5002
4       551234 | Li | 5003
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `read_csv()` as follows, keep in mind that the `sep` parameter accepts regular expression:

> sep : str, default ','
>       Delimiter to use. If sep is None, will try to automatically determine
>       this. Separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be
>       interpreted as regular expressions, will force use of the python parsing
>       engine and will ignore quotes in the data. Regex example: '\r\t'

so `|` needs to be escaped with `\`, otherwise it will be interpreted as `or` of patterns in regex:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

pd.read_csv(StringIO("""emp_num | Name | Salary
551234 | Joe | 5000
551234 | Dan | 5001
551234 | James | 5002
551234 | Li | 5003
551234 | Suzi | 5004"""), sep = " \| ")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use ".parse" like

```
import pandas as pd
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('file path')
df = xls_file.parse('Sheet1')
```

**output:**

```
   emp_num   Name   Salary
0   551234    Joe   5000
1   551234    Dan   5001
2   551234  James   5002
3   551234     Li   5003
4   551234   Suzi   5004
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read it as a csv file with sep="|".

Or you can read it into excel with separator "|" so it has multiple columns.

read_excel does not have a sep parameter.